# jQuery selector and object building

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this might been asked already, but need your help. I have 6-9 nodes need to create exact occurrence of jQuery object array of the same class. Here is the html and javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $element = $('.Grid--gutters');

  $miniStoryRow = $element.find('div[class*=js-ministory-row]');//This is not working

  //$miniStoryRow should contain 3(it can be 2 or 4 based on rows) objects 
  //which contain all element objects with the respective html
  //i.e. js-ministory-row0, js-ministory-row1, js-ministory-row2, js-ministory-row4

  $.each($miniStoryRow, function () {
    //should have 3 loops only based on html
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="Grid Grid--gutters">
  <div class="Grid-col js-ministory-row0">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="Img-Wrapper">
        <img src="img/banner-one-shoes.png">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid-col js-ministory-row0">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="Img-Wrapper">
        <img src="img/banner-one-tab.png">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid-col js-ministory-row0">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="Img-Wrapper">
        <img src="img/banner-one-tab.png">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid-col js-ministory-row1">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="Img-Wrapper">
        <img src="img/banner-one-shoes.png">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid-col js-ministory-row1">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="Img-Wrapper">
        <img src="img/banner-one-tab.png">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid-col js-ministory-row1">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="Img-Wrapper">
        <img src="img/banner-one-shoes.png">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid-col js-ministory-row2">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/banner-two-phones.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid-col js-ministory-row2">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/banner-one-tab.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pretty much I am looking for grouping an object with particular class.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: use `var clone =  $miniStoryRow.clone();`

Comment: Well I tried this by replacing `clone` and iterate through is not helping.

Comment: As every `js-ministory-rowX` element also has class `Grid-col`, and `Grid-col` is not otherwise used, you can select with `$miniStoryRow = $element.find('.Grid-col');`.

Comment: Your requirement that "$miniStoryRow should contain 3 ... objects" is unclear. Straightforwardly, `$miniStoryRow = $element.find('.Grid-col')` will select 8 elements, which can be filtered down to three ...... but which three do you want?

Comment: I think the fundamental issue is that there are no elements in the HTML that uniquely wrap each set of `js-ministory-rowX` elements. Fix the HTML and the jQuery will sort itself out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $element = $('.Grid--gutters');
  $miniStoryRow = $element.find('div[class*=js-ministory-row]');
  var len = $miniStoryRow.length;
  var groups = len / 3;
  for (var i=0; i<groups; i++) {
    $eachGroup = $element.find('div[class*=js-ministory-row'+i+']');
    $.each($eachGroup , function () {
        //do sth 
    });
  }
});
```

can this work?

Comment: This is static. there should be dynamic way to do it coz the `js-ministory-row'+i+'` contains `i` is not defined while program is running.

Comment: This is static. there should be dynamic way to do it coz the `js-ministory-row'+i+'` contains `i` is not defined while program is running.

Very nice try though. i Guess you mean `$.each($eachGroup, function ()..` if thats the case this is good alternative for some additional stuff is some one want to perform. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: you can write a function to **substr** the className, then push the **i** to an array, then loop the array.

Comment: +1. that can be done, with `push()`, I can achieve this through Array manipulation. But I have whole Analytics going to be included here. which is going to take all my js code limitation for this module. my hands are tight for code. I am already causing too much performance hit here `$element = $('.Grid--gutters');`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
$miniStoryRow = $element.find('div[class^="js-ministory-row"]');
```

Comment: This will only initialize with object array constructor and assign type but would not initialize objects or create another object array in side object.